# Replace callback in Handler

Tags: java, android, callback, handler, android-mediaplayer

I've a following problem. I have MediaPlayer and I use Handler to send messages about MediaPlayer's progress during it plays. And I want to be able change Handler's callback in runtime. When i change the playing file in MediaPlayer i use the following code:

```
player.setDataSource(filename);
player.prepare();
final int duration = player.getDuration();
player.start();
// removing previous callback
durationHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); 
// setting new callback
durationHandler.postDelayed(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {     
            int progress = player.getCurrentPosition();
            demonstrator.setProgress(progress, duration);           
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, REPEAT_TIME);         
        }       
    }, 400);
```

I expect the old callback will be replaced by new one. But it doesn't work! Both of callbacks are running! Why? And how can i avoid it?

Comment: both? i  see only one Runnable here...

Comment: btw if you want multiple actions, dont use Runnables, use Messages instead

Comment: >both? i see only one Runnable here...  I mean new and old callbacks. I tried to remove old callback by removeCallbacksAndMessages method and set new one with postDelayed method

Comment: as i said, better use custom Handler and override its handleMessage method...